# Find maximum of the output from reduce

Tags: equation-solving, functions, mathematical-optimization, symbolic, maximum

I am trying to reduce a function in two variables($n_1$ and $n_2$) whose domain is the set of Integers. I get a long list of pairs of values for these two variables(instead of a range). This could be because the range of $n_2$ changes for each $n_1$. I just want the maximum value of $n_1$ and $n_2$. Can you please guide me?

```
   driftParamSet = 1.9 - 0.2 Subscript[n, 2] + Subscript[n, 1] (-0.2 + (2.91434*10^-16 Subscript[n, 1])/(1. Subscript[n, 1] + 1.5 Subscript[n, 2]));
   driftγ = 17;
   Reduce[driftParamSet> -driftγ && Subscript[n, 1]>= 0 && Subscript[n, 2]>= 0,{Subscript[n, 1],Subscript[n, 2]}, Integers];
```

**Current output:**
$n_1=0\land n_2=1\left\|n_1=0\land n_2=2\right\|n_1=0\land n_2=3\|n_1=0\land n_2=4
\\......\\\left\|n_1=0\land n_2=90\right\|n_1=0\land n_2=91\|\\.....\\
 \left(n_1=92\land n_2=2\right)\lor \left(n_1=93\land n_2=0\right)\lor \left(n_1=93\land n_2=1\right)\lor \left(n_1=94\land n_2=0\right)$

**Expected output:**

$n_1$=94 and $n_2=$91

Comment: Several symbols in your code are undefined.  Please provide the definitions to aid the reader in answering your question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, sorry about that. I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the large result of `Reduce` be `rs`.  Then the maximum of each quantity is determined by

```
Max@Cases[rs, Equal[Subscript[n, 1], z_] -> z, Infinity]
(* 94 *)
Max@Cases[rs, Equal[Subscript[n, 2], z_] -> z, Infinity]
(* 94 *)
```

not `91` as speculated in the question.  The corresponding terms in `rs` can be obtained by

```
Position[rs, 94, Infinity]
(* {{94, 2, 2}, {4559, 1, 2}} *)

rs[[94]]
(* Subscript[n, 1] == 0 && Subscript[n, 2] == 94 *)

rs[[4559]]
(* Subscript[n, 1] == 94 && Subscript[n, 2] == 0 *)
```

Comment: thank you! To understand this better, the Cases[] function with the specified parameter creates a list of values of n1/n2 and the Max[] function operates on this list to give the maximum?

Comment: @gaganso  Precisely so.

Comment: @bbgodrey, the equation has changed slightly and have patterns of the form `19167.<=Subscript[n, 2]<=19486.`. I tried to use LessThanEqual in place of Equal with necessary changes but it doesn't seem to work. Should I ask a new question or update this?

Comment: @gaganso  I recommend asking a new question.  No one will notice a small change to an existing question.  In your new question, cite this question and explain how the new question differs.

Comment: I have created a new question here - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194075/parsing-output-of-a-reduce-operation

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use `Solve` after `Rationalize`ing input expressions:

```
driftParamSet = Rationalize[1.9 - 0.2 n2 + 
  n1 (-0.2 + (2.91434*10^-16 n1)/(1. n1 + 1.5 n2)), 10^-16]
driftγ = 17;
solutions = Solve[driftParamSet > -driftγ && n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0, {n1, n2}, Integers];

Max /@ Transpose[{n1, n2} /. solutions]
```

> {94, 94}

Yet another approach is using `ArgMax`:

```
Extract[ArgMax[{#, driftParamSet > -driftγ && n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0}, {n1, n2}, Integers]& /@ 
  {n1, n2}, {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]
```

> {94, 94}